# Count Tiles loaded from MBTiles

Tags: leaflet, mbtiles

I have created a MBTiles file from Tilemill and I am visualizing it through php MBTiles server. Its working fine. Now I want to count the loaded tiles and store it to a database. In a simple word I want to count how many tiles are loading when user is seeing the map. How can I do this?

Following is the php server code by which I am calling mbtiles

```
<?php
$zoom = $_GET['z'];
$column = $_GET['x'];
$row = $_GET['y'];
$db = $_GET['db'];
  try
  {
    // Open the database
    $conn = new PDO("sqlite:$db");

    // Query the tiles view and echo out the returned image
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tiles WHERE zoom_level = $zoom AND tile_column = $column AND tile_row = $row";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();

    $q->bindColumn(1, $zoom_level);
    $q->bindColumn(2, $tile_column);
    $q->bindColumn(3, $tile_row);
    $q->bindColumn(4, $tile_data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

    while($q->fetch())
    {
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo $tile_data;
    }
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

And using the following line to call tiles through that php file

```
var layer = L.tileLayer('../mbtiles.php?db=map.mbtiles&z={z}&x={x}&y={y}', {
                            tms: true,
                            maxZoom: 09,
                            minZoom: 05
                        });
```

Comment: Does the php server write access log?

Comment: I think there is no log access written in php. How can I do that?

Comment: No idea. If you had given an exact link to thing called "php MBTiles server" I would have tried to find its documentation, and if that does not help, to have a look at the source code.

Comment: I have updated my question with codes.

Comment: How about writing the log into the MBTiles database? Create a log table and insert new rows or just update tile counter with SQL `// Query the tiles view and echo out the returned image and write logging info`. But it may be that your web server is already logging the incoming php requests. With Apache it would go into access.log.

Comment: I am novice. Can you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: By another prepare- execute sql round I guess. I know nothing about php so I am the novice. The log table you can add with spatialite-GUI. I suppose it can open mbtiles databases.

Comment: PHP is being run by an actual webserver. Apache, nginx, lighttpd or something like that. That webserver almost certainly generates access logs that you can easily analyse. Otherwise, is a total number of tiles enough or do you want to know how often each tile was accessed individually.

Comment: I want to count individually accessed by user